# Android - get defauld DIAL and CALL application programmatically

Tags: android

Good day! I need to find out what applications (package names) are responsible for number dialing and calling.

I did something like

```
Intent dialIntent = new Intent();
dialIntent .setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL); //or ACTION_CALL
ComponentName compName = dialIntent .resolveActivity();
```

For both of this actions (ACTION_DIAL and ACTION_CALL) I get components with getPackageName() == "com.android.telephony", but I know, that my dialer is com.android.dialer and my calls go through com.android.phone . So how can I get default application's package names?

Comment: Try this .`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:" + your_phone_number);
                            intent.setData(uri);
                            startActivity(intent);`

Comment: You could not get `package name`

Comment: KeLiuyue, I dont need to launch dialer. I need packagename itself. You sure I cannot get it?

Comment: If you do not launch dialer ,I don't to do it .Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to check TelecomManager. Looks like [`getSystemService(TelecomManager::class.java).defaultDialerPackage`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/telecom/TelecomManager?hl=en#getdefaultdialerpackage) is what you want. Also you can listen to Intent [ACTION_DEFAULT_DIALER_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/telecom/TelecomManager?hl=en#ACTION_DEFAULT_DIALER_CHANGED:kotlin.String), which will be sent out each time the default dialer has changed.

Answer (score 0):

To get the system default dialer app package name, use the following code:

```
// This method will return system dialer app package name,
// as system dialer app is always at index 0.
private String getSystemDialerApp() {
        Intent dialerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        List<ResolveInfo> mResolveInfoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(dialerIntent, 0);
        return mResolveInfoList.get(0).activityInfo.packageName;
    }
```

If you want a list of application which can dial phone, then use the below code, as it is:

```
// This method will return package name of all dialer apps.
public List<String> getPackagesOfDialerApps(Context context){

    List<String> packageNames = new ArrayList<>();

    // Declare action which target application listen to initiate phone call
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    // Query for all those applications
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    // Read package name of all those applications
    for(ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfos){
        ActivityInfo activityInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo;
        packageNames.add(activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
    }

    return packageNames;
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem!